# IllegalStateException only when running from command shell

Tags: java, eclipse

- when launching our product in eclipse and all works fine
- when launching the product from command shell i'm getting an `IllegalStateException`.

the exception is thrown when quitting the program.

And yes, somehow it's an obvious reason why the exception is thrown but i still don't have any idea on how to get track of that error.

-> how can i debug an application that throws exceptions **only** when started from command shell but **not** from eclipse?

-> any other idea on how to track that issue?

> Exception in thread "AWT-Windows" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
>           at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211)
>           at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lambda$registerShutdownHook$263(WToolkit.java:282)
>           at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$$Lambda$33/16669899.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.registerShutdownHook(WToolkit.java:279)
>           at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:297)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[image]

the reason for that exception in general is, that you try to add a shutdown hook and the application has already quit.

Comment: This looks more like Swing than SWT

Comment: the error message looks like - but we don't use any swing components (at least not on our GUI)

Comment: Do you perform some operation when shutting down the operations??

Comment: obviously we're doing some a lot of operation on shutdown and i cannot determine which one is responsible for that error

Comment: Something is using Swing/AWT because that is not code SWT every uses.

Comment: Does the full stacktrace contain any of your classes? If so, which line is responsible for the exception?

Comment: point taken i'll remove the swt-tag

Comment: that's the full error log - sadly none of our classes seems to be responsible -  that's why i'm so desperated to ask (such a stupid)  question on SO

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631684/what-is-the-cause-and-resolution-of-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-error) help?

Comment: @Baz looks interesting... i'll dig into that a bit deeper - any further ideas are apprechiated!! (bw - it's not a swing application, the AWT-Windows-thread is the thread that handles the system UI events)

Comment: @Baz that helped... i found the thread that was not able to be shutdown....

Comment: uhm - weird... that was my answer that helped me out!

Comment: @MartinFrank Heh, now that's funny!

Comment: now thats really funny, all i did was adding `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(processingThread);` to a potiental thread!

Comment: just as described in my answer!

Comment: @MartinFrank Well there you go. Should we close as duplicate then?

Comment: please do so! it's solved with 'my' answer on the other topic !

Comment: @Baz one mystery is left: why it the exception not thrown when using eclipse?

Comment: @MartinFrank it might have something to do with the programme being run in eclipse's JVM. Not sure though